# How to efficiently set multiple related keys in redis?

Tags: bash, redis-cli

I want to execute the following in a bash script:

```
num_total_keys=0x1FFFF

for ((i = 0; i <= $num_total_keys; i++))
do
    redis-cli SET some_prefix:$i True > /dev/null
done
```

When I execute this, however, it takes a really long time. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule of thumb:

If your command accept pipelined data/instructions; do not run your command repeatedly in a shell loop, but build all of it before piping to your command as a single call like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

i=131071

while [ $i -ge 0 ]; do
  printf 'SET some_prefix:%d True\n' $i
  i=$((i - 1))
done | redis-cli --pipe
```

Alternatively using Bash's [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```sh
printf 'SET some_prefix:%d True\n' {131071..0} | redis-cli --pipe
```

Comment: These commands run around 10x faster if you use `redis-cli --pipe` Have a look here... https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert

Comment: Thank you so much for these tips. I would just like to add that in Linux systems, `\r\n` might need to be used instead of `\n` in the `printf` command. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093371/5762785